# How long should I keep trying to solve my own problem before asking?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering what an appropriate period is for looking for an answer to a particular problem (both here and elsewhere) before asking on an SO site?  Usually the questions I've asked have been answered in 10 minutes or so, so it really makes no sense to spend an hour trying to solve a problem before asking.  What is a general consensus?

Comment: You just ask immediately. We don't get rep if you solve your own problem =)

Answer (score 9):

I'd ask it right away.  Even if you figure it out, it'll leave a trail for the next person to look it up...

Comment: And if you figure it out, post the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It really is up to you.

I personally prefer to spend half an hour to an hour at least trying to figure it on my own, since as a side effect I usually learn quite a lot more than just the solution to my problem.

However, if you are in a tight schedule and have a deadline looming over you, do a quick search on SO and ask right away if you don't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you got a question, please just ask it, even if a short google search might work. The whole point of Stackoverflow, in my mind, is to shortcut the google searching required to answer programming questions. So the more questions the better SO will become.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it takes you to do a good Google search, or two, to try and find the solution on your own.  But in reality, it doesn't much matter as there is no conceivable way to verify that you waited at all.
BTW: Welcome to SO, don't forget to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq

Answer (score 2):

At the least do a Google search. I've noticed numerous questions here where the accepted answer was copied verbatim from the first hit on a Google search for the question title.

It's also useful to put in your question the steps you took and, if applicable, possible solutions that have already been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Straight away. You'll get some reputation points and quite often I've learned more from the variety of answers and comments here than I would have learned working it out myself in isolation.

Oh, and did I mention the reputation points. And Badges! Shiny badges!

Answer (score 0):

Search here first, and if you find a similar question that doesn't suit, ask your question here, reference the other question and say why it doesn't suit.  Personally, I'd ask here **and** google.  I'd also tend to have a rummage around the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/), [Source forge](http://sourceforge.net/), and [Code Guru](http://www.codeguru.com/).  Some very good programmers will spend more time on one site than another, so it's worth searching them all.  I've had some great answers here but also drawn some blanks.  Using SO exclusively, will IMHO make you less resourceful in the long run.  Just because it is a great site, that is not an excuse to be lazy.